Handle issue "PlatformNotSupportedException" for HttpClientHandler.SslProtocol in .netstandard2.0 project
I have .netstandard2.0 project which is used by two projects. One is .net core project and one is .netframework4.7.1. I'm getting "PlatformNotSupportedException" for HttpClientHandler.SslProtocol while referring my .Netstandard2.0 project in .netframework4.7.1. I know it is not supported in .netframework4.7.1.But I want to skip that code .netframework4.7.1 and don't skip in .netcore.How can I handle this in .netstansard2.0.
I don't have access to both .netframework4.7.1 and .net core.I have access only to .netstandard2.0 where the "HttpClientHandler.SslProtocol" using. I could do anything in .netframework4.7.1 and .net core. What I can do in .netstandard2.0?
Working fine in .netcore.
This is my code
    private static readonly HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { 
        AutomaticDecompression = System.Net.DecompressionMethods.GZip | System.Net.DecompressionMethods.Deflate, 
        ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = null, 
        SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls11 
    })
    {
        Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(45)
    };

Below code is when implemented ihttpclientfactory
    private static readonly Lazy<IHttpClientFactory> httpClientFactoryLazy = new Lazy<IHttpClientFactory>(() =>
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddHttpClient("HttpClientFactory", client =>
        {
            client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
        })
          .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
          {
              var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
              handler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
              handler.SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls11;
              return handler;
          });
        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        return serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();
    });

Can we use below code identify framework version and do the codes accordingly?
private string GetCallingFramework()
{
    return RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription;
}


Can you show us actual code? It's much easier to help when we can see exactly the problem you have.

Don't put it in a comment, [edit] it into the question.

@DavidG code added

Tls11 is deprecated in Net Core. Its insecure don't use it. Even in Net Framework.

@DotNetCoder the code you posted is a humongous security risk, trying to enable the obsolete TLS 1.1 protocol that's explicitly disabled in all cloud services, all supported Windows versions. Just delete handler.SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.... and let the OS use the best available algorithm

@DotNetCoder why are you using SslProtocols.Tls11 in the first place? It matters - that's disabled everywhere for years. Whatever you're calling almost certainly supports TLS 1.2 already and will probably reject calls made with 1.1. Even if you call your own internal service, you had to explicitly re-enable TLS 1.1. I suspect the real solution is to remove any attempts to force the TLS version

@PanagiotisKanavos In Docker environment, we are getting error while using TLS 1.2.But it is working when used TLS1.1. The api we are consuming is of third party owned one.

Docker doesn't break TLS 1.2. If it did, nobody would be able to call any cloud services. What's the actual error? You should fix the bug instead of assuming TLS 1.2 is broken. Even if the third party service requires TLS 1.1, it's no solution to prevent yourself from using TLS 1.2 when they finally fix their security issues. If that service is hosted on AWS or Azure, it will be forced to move to 1.2 in a few months, when both providers turn off 1.1. Use SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls12

To handle the difference between .NET Standard and .NET 4.x, you need to be able to compile the library to target both platforms. To do this, first change your library .csproj file to support multiple target frameworks:
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard20;net471</TargetFrameworks>
  ....
</PropertyGroup>

Now in your code you can choose how you handle the different frameworks using one of the preprocessor symbols that is defined for you. For example:
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
//snip

#if NETSTANDARD2_0
    handler.SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls11;
#endif

//snip

#if NET471
    // In .NET 4.x we must use the ServicePointManager class
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;
#endif


Given that TLS 1.1 is disabled on all supported Windows versions, cloud and third party providers, the real solution could be to just remove this code. I suspect the OP is trying to maintain legacy code that's no longer needed

@PanagiotisKanavos Possibly, I almost added that as a side bar, but there are some legitimate (though rare) situations where this may be needed.

@DavidG Can I use 'private string GetCallingFramework()
{
        return RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription;
    }'   to identify framework?


@DotNetCoder Why need that instead of compiler symbols? I assume that your docker build process (presumably using net core) is different then the one for net framework?

@Ralf When I run in both environment(netcore and .netframework471) the #if NETSTANDARD2_0 become true.
